# Php array remove duplicate and put toghether in another array

Tags: php, arrays

I have this php array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2505
            [1] => Lima 
            [2] => Daniels
            [3] => 0996995904
            [4] => 
            [5] => 755971
            [6] => 1454284800
            [7] => Cat. A (Moto)
            [8] => 0
            [9] => 1
            [10] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2505
            [1] => Lima 
            [2] => Daniels
            [3] => 0996995904
            [4] => 
            [5] => 755971
            [6] => 1454284800
            [7] => Cat. A (Moto)
            [8] => 1
            [9] => 0
            [10] => 0
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2505
            [1] => Lima 
            [2] => Daniels
            [3] => 0996995904
            [4] => 
            [5] => 755971
            [6] => 1454284800
            [7] => Cat. A (Moto)
            [8] => 0
            [9] => 0
            [10] => 0
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2525
            [1] => Lomarca
            [2] => Miro
            [3] => 0099778877
            [4] => 
            [5] => 768131
            [6] => 1454976000
            [7] => Cat. A (Moto)
            [8] => 1
            [9] => 0
            [10] => 0
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2525
            [1] => Lomarca
            [2] => Miro
            [3] => 0099778877
            [4] => 
            [5] => 768131
            [6] => 1454976000
            [7] => Cat. A (Moto)
            [8] => 0
            [9] => 1
            [10] => 0
        )

)
```

I want i new array:
1) if element [0] exists in the array I want to control elements 8, 9 and 10 and if one of this is 1 I want to have 1 in the final array, but I don't want to have the same array 2 times (the index [0] is the key).

My final array shound be:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2505
            [1] => Lima 
            [2] => Daniels
            [3] => 0996995904
            [4] => 
            [5] => 755971
            [6] => 1454284800
            [7] => Cat. A (Moto)
            [8] => 1
            [9] => 1
            [10] => 1
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2525
            [1] => Lomarca
            [2] => Miro
            [3] => 0099778877
            [4] => 
            [5] => 768131
            [6] => 1454976000
            [7] => Cat. A (Moto)
            [8] => 1
            [9] => 1
            [10] => 0
        )
)
```

I have only one time the index 2505 and 2505 and index 8 and 9  and 10 are 1 for the 2505 and the index 8 and 9 are 1 for the 2525.

Comment: why does the item `2525` have `[10] => 0` in the output?

Comment: I think because #3 and #4 both have [10]=>0, so an `OR` will yield 0.

Comment: Poster, What is the Primary key? Element [0] or something else?

Comment: yes,  it's like an OR.

Comment: the primary key is the element with index 0 (2505, 2525...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this does the job: (assuming that your first array is `$arrays` and your desired result is `$result`)

```
 $result = array();
 foreach($arrays as $array)
 {
      if(!isset($result[$array[0]]))
      {
           $result[$array[0]] = $array;
      }
      else
      {
           $result[$array[0]][8]  = $array[8]  == 1 ? 1 : $result[$array[0]][8];
           $result[$array[0]][9]  = $array[9]  == 1 ? 1 : $result[$array[0]][9];
           $result[$array[0]][10] = $array[10] == 1 ? 1 : $result[$array[0]][10];
      }
 }
```

but wherever you get your data from, e.g. a database, I would use `element[0]` as the key, so you don't get multiple entries in `$arrays`. Another option would be to create a class which holds your data...